How to extract the business hours in a JSON object with BigQuery
JSON Structure
I am writing to request your assistance in extracting business hours from the provided JSON object of UberEats.
According to the following instructions, I have to perform the task.

Take the first key value pair in the menu dictionary and the first section and assume that as the store business hours.
Note: daysBitArray starts with Monday and indicates the days of the week for this time window is applicable. The might be more than element in the regularHours array.

Please use json parsing and do not use regex.

You can use unnest to flatten business hours array in JSON


After spending considerable time on this task, I have formulated the following query:
SELECT
vb_name,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(value, '$.regularHours[0].startTime') AS start_time,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(value, '$.regularHours[0].endTime') AS end_time
FROM
`arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours`,
UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(response, '$.data.menus.26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705.sections')) AS value;

This query successfully retrieves the vb_name, start_time, and end_time for the provided key (26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705). However, when I remove the provided key, I receive no output, and it indicates that there is no data to display in the BigQuery. Additionally, despite trying various combinations, I have been unsuccessful in extracting the business hours (start and end time) for all the keys present in the response column.
Note: It is a dynamic key present in each row of the response column.
(Note: response is the name of the column where I have JSON data)
I would greatly appreciate your assistance or guidance in successfully extracting the business hours (start and end time) for all the keys present in the response column, in accordance with the provided JSON of UberEats.
Alternatively, you could provide me with another approach or query that can successfully extract business hours according to the provided JSON of UberEats.

Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to you question as editable text (so that someone can copy it if they want to try a solution). Also, please update your question with the result you want to achieve based on your source data

The provided image is a JSON structure of that column where I have the JSON data.
I want to extract the start and end times for all the keys present in the column(response) where I have JSON data.
